# How to submit update to existing apk in android developer conole using eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, updates, developer-console

I have a publish app on Google Play Store, Now I have made some changes in the application and I want to release the update version.
I have signed the .apk using same keystore, alias and password which I used for first upload. 
But the problem is when the new release get published, it does not show 'update' option on the play store. 
I am using eclipse.
Any solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have incremented the version for everything appropriately there should be an update available. The versioning is managed in the manifest.

Comment: What did you do to upload the new release? I usually do this manually from my Google Play Developer Console.

Comment: I have properly incremented the versioning @zgc7009

Comment: I generated the signed apk using eclipse, then uploaded it manually on the Google Play Developer Console @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Does your update appear in your developer console? If so, give it some time. The update will not appear immediately on Google Play Store.

Comment: Also, what "update option" are you looking for? Did you install your own app from Google Play Store?

Comment: Thanks, I asked one of my friend to check for update.